# If $X$ is ordered, do the half-open intervals form a base of a topology on $X$?

Tags: general-topology

I'm currently reading a beginner's book on topology. In one of its exercises one is supposed to show the following:

> If $(X,\leq)$ is a totally ordered set, then $\mathcal{B}:=\{[a,b) \mid a,b \in X, a\leq b\}$ is a base of a unique topology on $X$.

Now, if we can prove existence then uniqueness follows, since topologies with the same bases coincide.

What bothers me is that I think we can't guarantee the existence of such a topology. For example, let $X= (-\infty, 0]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. If the statement was right, we would be able to write $X$ as  union of intervals $[a,b)$ with $a\leq b$, however for all $a,b\in X$ we have $0 \notin [a,b)$. Thus this is not possible.

Am I missing something or is the statement indeed wrong?

Comment: You are correct. If $X$ has a maximal element, then half-open intervals indeed do not form a base of a topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need that $X$ does not have a maximum, because then (and only then) do we have that $\bigcup \mathcal{B}=X$, which is a necessary condition to be a base.

(if $M$ is maximal, it cannot be in any $[a,b)$ as this implies $M > b$, which cannot be. And if $x\in X$ is arbitary and there is no maximum, we pick some $y > x$ (as $x$ is not the maximum) and then $x \in [x,y) \in \mathcal{B}$)